# remove button when pressed in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

How do I remove a button after pressing it in p5.js? I've tried the following code but it doesn't do anything.

```
var button
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 550);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  button = createButton("Press to continue")
  button.position(100,525)
  button.mousePressed(function(){button.remove()})
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are recreating the button on every frame. If you move your button creation code to your setup function it should work.

```js
var button
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 550);
  button = createButton("Press to continue")
  button.position(100,525)
  button.mousePressed(function(){button.remove()})
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
</body>
</html>
```